# clarification on integrating slack api in the xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio, slack-api

I am working on a Xamarin App in which we need to have a feature as Open chat room or discussion room. I was exploring the slack api and interested to integrate the slack api in the App.

My clarification is, on integrating slack client api in the app, whether chat feature will be enabled? Whether my app registered users can utilize the slack chat room ? Or do the app registered users has also to register in the slack?

Comment: https://api.slack.com

Comment: @jason .. thank you .. I am little confused with slack .. Can i use slack api and use the discussion feature in my App .. or do we need to build an app on slack platform ???

Comment: It need not to be slack, if there is any other third party api available with similar discussion forum, i am willing to do some prototype with that ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Slack API is not much use if you do not plan to work with the core Slack application as well. So if you are just looking to extend your own app with a chat features, the Slack API will not help you much. To utilize the Slack chat features, you need to setup your own Slack team and your users will need to register on the Slack team and use it. The Slack API mainly enables one to build automation and bots around a Slack team.

Comment: thank you .. this makes sense to me ..!!! do we have any alternate as similar to chat room feature .. any third party API ??

Answer (score 1):

QuickBlox is another 3rd-party SDK that you can use.

xamarin chat sample https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-chat-xamarin/

Comment: Thank you @Mohamed